# Some files are being ignored even if they are not in my gitignore, are there any other ignore files other than gitignore?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I created 2 new projects in my solution and although it commits all the files, it ignores my .csproj files (it even shows "ignored" on visual studio).

I verified that my .gitignore had no such weird ignores. Also, when I clicked to "add to source control", there was no changes on my .gitignore.

Perhaps I am failing to understand something basic about how source control is acting on my solution folder, but I am just worried that it fails to commit/push all files as not all files are visible in visual studio.

So, are there any other ignore files than gitignore?

Comment: Worth reading the doc: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that Visual Studio, as described [in its tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/ignore-files) has setup a system-wide gitignore file:

```
 git config core.excludesfile C:\Users\frank\.gitignore_global
```

With that declaration, you can have "other ignore files other than gitignore".

Do a `git config -l` from within your repo to check for any "gitignore" or "exclude" declaration line.

Comment: FWIW, VS 2015 (thankfully) does not do this out of the box, this would need to be a manual step on the cmdline.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Good to know. Other tools do that (SourceTree for instance)

Comment: Whoa, I had no idea.